# How does this code compare numbers in the list and output the maximum?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
myList=[1,2,3]
max=myList[0]

for i in range(1,len(myList)):
    if myList[i]>max:
        max=myList[i]

print(max)
```

It stores the number in first slot in a temporary variable and compares the 2 other numbers to the temporary variable.

How does it know which one is maximum?

It only stores:

```
myList[1] = max if myList[1] > max and 
myList[2] = max if myList[2] > max
```

There's no comparsion between myList[1] and myList[2] in the code.

How does the program know myList[2] is larger than myList[1] in here?

Comment: You store the largest value in `max` so as long as the next value in the list is greater than it (`if myList[i] > max: ...`), it will update the `max` value guaranteeing that `max` contains the largest value in the list.

Comment: Because `max` is sequentially updated whenever you encounter something greater than the running maximum. Note that `max` is not a good name because that's also a python built-in

Comment: `myList[1] > max` => `max = myList[1]`. Then, `myList[2] > max`, thus, the code does compare `myList[1]` and `myList[2]`.

Comment: @Yolanda Hui, you got many good answers. Assuming that one of these helped you, please mark the one that you find the most helpful as the answer for this question. Thanks and welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works just the way you might handle it with a large list on paper.  You don't keep track of the *position* of the largest element, merely its value.

You start by looking at the first element, and marking that value as the max.  At this point, it's also the minimum, and the median, and the mean, and ...  :-)

Now, go down the list, one element at a time.  Compare the element with the max.  If the element is larger, then update the max to be that new, higher value.  There is no *explicit* check of `myList[1]` vs `mylist[2]`.  What happens is this, assuming (as you did) that myList[1] > myList[0]:

```
max = myList[0]           # myList[0] and max are now the same value
while ...
   if mylist[1] > max:    # This compares myList[1] > myList[0]
       max = myList[1]    # myList[1] and max are now the same value
   ... # Next loop iteration, i=2
   if myList[2] > max     # THIS is where you compare myList[2] and the value of myList[1]
   ...
```

Does that clear up the operation?  If not, try adding some basic tracing:

```
for i in range(1, len(myList)):
    print(i, myList[1], max)
    if myList[i] > max:
        max = myList[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `max` here (poor variable name choice, considering `max()` is a built-in function in Python) is continually updated in the loop. If the current iteration of the for loop yields an element in `myList` that exceeds `max` in value, then `max` is assigned to that value and the loop continues to the next iteration until it has reached the end of `myList`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a comparison - if needed...
There are 2 possible cases:

1. If `myList[1] > myList[0]` then `max = myList[1]` and in the next iteration it compares `myList[2]` with `max`, which is similar to comparing `myList[2]` with `myList[1]`.
2. If `myList[1] <= myList[0]` then `max` remains equals to `myList[0]`. In this case **we don't need to compare** `myList[2]` with `myList[1]`, because we already know that `myList[0]` is greater than or equals to `myList[1]`, so we only need to compare `myList[2]` with `myList[0]`

This is a rather compact example, but it is true for larger lists...

Hope that it makes sense, comment if you need more clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

1- your max is set to the first element in the array -> max = 1

2- your comparing max to the elements in the list starting from the second 
position( in this case number 2)

3- 2 > 1 , so max is updated to number 2

3- you compare the new max(number 2) to number 3

4- 3>2 , so max is updated to number 3

5- you have reached the end of your list

6- max is printed - 3

Comment: @rahlf23 answered first.

Answer (score 0):

The "max" variable just keep the maximum number that was assigned to it.
In every steps of the loop, if the given number from list is bigger than the "max" variable, we assign that number to the "max".